# Using interceptor with Hibernate Template

Tags: hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee, interceptor

i am trying to inject EmptyInterceptor implementation in the Hibernate Template.But this interceptor is not functioning  at runtime.
Does there is any other condition that need to fulfilled for interceptor to work like scope of bean whom we are injecting interceptor should be session or something else

```
 <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
    <property name="entityInterceptor">
    <ref bean="interceptor"/>
    </property>
```

problem solved by adding the Interceptor in the sesssion factory class

Comment: So what is the behaviour you are seeing? Please can you paste more code/configuration?

Comment: my coding is running normally,that is not going inside code that i have impemented in the interceptor

Comment: This problem is solved by adding interceptor in the session factory class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is solved by adding the Interceptor in the sesssion factory class instead of template

Answer (score 0):

By using code in HIbernate5

```
template.getSessionFactory().withOptions()
      .interceptor(interceptor)
```